# How to filter files from directory using LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

In my program c#, i am using LINQ to fetch all file from directory for processing as following

```
var FilesToProcess = from filePath in Directory.GetFiles(sDirectory)
                        where File.GetCreationTime(filePath).BusinessDaysUntil(DateTime.Today)
                        select filePath;
if (FilesToProcess.Any())
{
    List<string> process = (from string s in FilesToProcess
                            where ((s.EndsWith(".ext")) || (s.EndsWith(".xml")))
                            select s).ToList();
}
```

But In my case i have xml and txt files of same name like A.xml and A.txt similarly B.xml and B.txt and same for others.

I want to use LINQ to fetch both files of same name for processing as following

> Processfile(string xmlfile, string txtfile)

As per my above code, i am getting all files(xml, txt) from directory, but i don't know to proceed further.

Please help to filter the files of same name but different extention?

Answer (score 12):

You can use the [Linq GroupBy method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx) to do this, eg:

```
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(sDirectory);
var filePairs = directory
            .GetFiles("*.xml")
            .Union(directory.GetFiles("*.txt"))
            .GroupBy(file => file.Name);
```

Or if you wish to get just the files in pairs:

```
var filePairs = directory
            .GetFiles("*.xml")
            .Union(directory.GetFiles("*.txt"))
            .GroupBy(file => file.Name)
            .Select(grp => new
            {
                 XmlFile = grp.FirstOrDefault(file => file.Extension == "xml"),
                 TxtFile = grp.FirstOrDefault(file => file.Extension == "txt")
            })
            .Where(pair => pair.XmlFile != null && pair.TxtFile!= null);
```

Comment: If using .NET4 or later, it might be better to use [`EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles.aspx) rather than `GetFiles`: it'll stream the results rather than banging out a single array.

Comment: I used above code, i have 2 txt and 2 xml file in directory. I am getting null. Can you help what mistake i did, i copied exactly same code

Comment: @HemantKothiyal Please post your updated code and the error you are getting.